# Unable to get map function for http.get in Angular 2.0 Final Release

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm using Angular 2.0 final release and unable to see map function to retrieve data , only subscribe is available and Unable to get data using that

Having below imports

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Headers, Http, Response,} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
// Operators
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';    
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

Code:

```
this._http.get("myUrl").subscribe();
```

tried even this

```
var myData: any;
this._http.get("data/landing/users.json").subscribe(res => this.myData = res)
```

still myData is undefined.

Any help on how to  retrieve Data from service

Comment: import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; Observable.of().map();

Comment: Used all the imports you have mentioned , Kindly see edited code, and where to use "Observable.of().map();  " ??

Comment: this._http.get("data/landing/users.json").map(response => response.json()).subscribe(result => this.myData = result.json())  some thing like that.